# Why do I get this error when I select an option in the third dropdown or if i select an option in the first for second time? livewire

Tags: laravel, dropdown, laravel-livewire

mi page has 3 dropdowns they works following this steps:

1. the first dropdown called client the user can select a user.
2. the dropdown called company doesn't not depend of client dropdown
3. the dropdown called period depends only of company dropdown

this only works when you select a client and company in order

here the step that doesn't work:

- ***select an option in the company dropdown and then select an opcion in
  client dropdown or period dropdown***

when I do this I get this error:
[image]

but the debug says that `$option` is not a array, it is an object

[image]

here is my livewire component code:

```
    public $clientOptionSelected, $companyOptionSelected, $periodOptionSelected;
public $clientOptions = [], $companyOptions = [], $periodOptions = [];

protected $rules = [
    'clientOptionSelected' =>  'required',
    'companyOptionSelected' => 'required',
    'periodOptionSelected' => 'required'
];

public function updated($propertyName)
{
    $this->validateOnly($propertyName);
}

public function render()
{
    $this->clientOptions = DB::select('exec SP_PG @opc=:opc',['opc' => 4]);
    $this->companyOptions = DB::select('exec SP_PG @opc=:opc',['opc' => 5]);
    return view('livewire.create-company-component');
}

public function submit()
{
    $this->validate();
   //$result = DB::select('exec SP_PG @opc=:opc , @idCliente=:idCliente , @idBaseDatos=:idVaseDatos',['opc' => 7,'idCliente' =>$this->clientOptionSelected,'idBaseDatos' => $this->periodOptionSelected]);
}

public function updatedCompanyOptionSelected()
{
    $this->periodOptions = DB::select('exec SP_PG @opc=:opc,@descripcion=:descripcion',['opc' => 6 , 'descripcion' => $this->companyOptionSelected]); 
}
```

And my HTML code:

```html
<div>
    <form wire:submit.prevent="submit" method="POST">
        @csrf
        <label>Selecciona un Cliente</label>
        <select wire:model="clientOptionSelected" name="client" class="form-control" id="cbxCliente">
            <option value="">Selecciona una opción</option>
            @foreach ($clientOptions as $option)
                <option value="{{ $option->val }}">{{ $option->text }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
        @error('clientOptionSelected')
            <span class="error">{{ $message }}</span>
        @enderror
        <br>
        <label>Selecciona una Empresa</label>
        <select wire:model="companyOptionSelected" name="company" class="form-control" id="cbxEmpresa">
            <option value="">Selecciona una opción</option>
            @foreach ($companyOptions as $option)
                <option value="{{ $option->val }}">{{ $option->text }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
        @error('companyOptionSelected')
            <span class="error">{{ $message }}</span>
        @enderror
        <br>
        <label>Selecciona una Periodo</label>
        <div wire:loading.remove>
            <select wire:model="periodOptionSelected" name="period" class="form-control" id="cbxPeriodo">
                <option value="">Selecciona una opción</option>
                @foreach ($periodOptions as $option)
                    <option value="{{ $option->val }}">{{ $option->text }}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
        @error('periodOptionSelected')
            <span class="error">{{ $message }}</span>
        @enderror
        <div wire:loading class="form-control spinner-border" role="status">
            <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
        </div>
        <br>
        <button class="btn btn-success" id="btnSave">Guardar</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

**NEW**

I found this, when I use the second select the value of the variable called `$periodOptions` is

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [val] => 
        [text] => Selecciona una opción
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [val] => 79
        [text] => AHL Quincena
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [val] => 80
        [text] => Periodo Extraordinario
    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [val] => 81
        [text] => PTR MENSUAL
    )

[4] => stdClass Object
    (
        [val] => 82
        [text] => PTR mensual NO TIMBRAR
    )

 )
```

but then when I select an option on the third or first select the value changes for this:

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [val] => 
        [text] => Selecciona una opción
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [val] => 57
        [text] => COL QUINCENA
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [val] => 58
        [text] => NNB QUINCENAL
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [val] => 59
        [text] => PAN QUINCENAL
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [val] => 60
        [text] => Periodo Extraordinario
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [val] => 61
        [text] => Quincenal
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [val] => 62
        [text] => STU BIF NITTI QUINCENAL
    )

)
1
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because this is set to an array?

```
$periodOptions = []; <-- Why array?

<select wire:model="periodOptionSelected"
```

Try

```
$periodOptions = "";
```

**EDIT**

Try replacing **$option->val** with **$option['val']** and make sure you convert your options var to an array beforehand to be on the safe side. It could be an internal automatic conversion of Livewire of obj to array for selects.

Comment: If this is the only thing causing the problem, the question should be flagged for closure, not answered. Problems caused by typos and similar errors are off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: thnks man, but I didn't work there are so many PeriodOptions so I needs to be an array

Comment: Ahh yes sorry, I was very tired and confused options with optionsSelected...
I edited my answer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).